# std::move of *this and later access to class methods and fields

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I understand it is something stupid to do with code... but for the sake of understanding, please consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct S;
void f( S && s );

struct S {
  S() : i{std::vector<int>(10, 42)} {}
  std::vector<int> i;
  void call_f() { f( std::move(*this) ); }
  void read() { std::cout << " from S: " <<  i.at(3) << std::endl; }
};

void f(S && s)  { std::cout << " from f: " <<  s.i.at(3) << std::endl; }

int main() {
  S s;
  s.call_f();
  s.read();
}
```

This compiles and run for both g++ and clang++, while I would expect that the `std::vector<int>` to be moved. Running this in gdb and looking at the memory shows that the address of `s.i` is not set to zero after the `std::move`, while I expected that for non-POD types it would.
Therefore, I expected a segfault from this piece of code.
Could please anyone explain me this behaviour? Why is not neither `s` nor its inner field invalidated? Is it a feature with `this`?

Comment: Never "expect" a segfault! Even if you write code that _can_ cause one (you didn't), expecting one is folly.

Comment: std::move(*this) does not move anything, it tells the compiler that it's OK to call the move overload of f. If the implementation of the move overload of f doesn't mess with s, then your s instance is still good. If you want your segfault, you'd have to add something that effectively moves s.i inside of f.

Comment: @rectummelancolique: Hi there. This is the comment section. Please put answers down there ↓↓↓↓↓ so that they may be subject to the peer review features that set SE Q&A apart from its message board / forum forebears. Thanks!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, just thought that quick blurb didn't really warrant a full blown response, but fair enough!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::move` doesn't actually move anything, it just casts to an rvalue to *allow* moving (bit of a misnomer, but hey, we're stuck with it now).

If you were to do an actual move construction, you'd most likely see an exception from the bounds-checked `std::vector::at`.

```
void f(S && s) { 
    S steal = std::move(s);
    std::cout << " from f: " <<  s.i.at(3) << std::endl;
}
```

GCC 6.1 gives me this

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 3) >= this->size() (which is 0)
bash: line 7: 18043 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that vector has 10 elements initialized to 42

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Ahaha whoops

Comment: And yes this is why `std::move` is not only "a bit of a misnomer" but an absolutely horrid name for what it does. Tsk!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit once the initial surprise has been dealt with, I'm glad it wasn't named `std::enable_moving`.

Comment: @Quentin Why not `std::give_me_something_I_can_move_just_in_case`?

Answer (score 1):

`std::move` does not move anything - it only returns an xvalue referenceing the same object that can be bound to an rvalue so that a moving ctor or moving operator= can be invoked.

So in your code no move is ever done - `f` just operates on an rvalue reference to the same object.

If `f` accepted `S` by value then there would be a move and you would see the `i` being empty.

Comment: _"you would see the behaviour you expected"_ Not quite.

Comment: fair enough, "you would see the effect of moving" would be more correct.